# Access-Control-Allow-Origin Problem in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, cors

I have an issue when I try to access the backend.

Questions:

1. Do have any configure CORS in ReactJs?(in axios create or ..)
2. Are there any best way to do the CORS configuration in Spring Boot and ReactJs?

configurations are following below what I done,

Access to `XMLHttpRequest` at `'http://localhost:8282/opsprime/api/products?title_contains=a'` from origin `'http://localhost:3000'` has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

So, I configured the backend(spring boot) as,

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class TestController {
....
}
```

and this is the reactJs configuration,

```
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8282/opsprime/api',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {
         'Authorization' : `Bearer 4b21949a-4829-43cc-asex-1d0512478676`
       }
  });
```

Comment: I guess you are working with chrome, which has the policy to block every cors request. For develoopment you have to install an extention like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf), which allows cors requests on your browser.

Comment: I did this before..

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your spring boot application configuration, you can change the value of CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW to identify on which methods CROSS can be implemented.

```
@Configuration
public class CorsSecurity implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final String[] CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW = {"/**"};

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        for (String cors : CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW)
            registry.addMapping(cors).allowedOrigins("*").allowedHeaders("*").allowedMethods("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a problem in my pom file (oauth dependency) so, I did disable that and restart the server then that worked. Then I added the oauth dependency. Its work properly